# Setting values for two IDs for self.location

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function

```
function reload2(form)
{   
    var val=form.loc.options[form.loc.options.selectedIndex].value;
    var val2 = form.category.options[form.category.options.selectedIndex].value;
    self.location='upload.php?category=' + val2;

}
```

In the function the values of val 1 is storing the value of id 'loc' and val2 is storing the value of id = 'category'.

The `self.location` is setting only category to value 2 but i also want the value of `loc` to become `val1`. ( so that on reloading, values of both `loc` and `category` are preserved).

What should i do in order to achieve that?

Comment: self.location='upload.php?category=' + val2 + '&loc=' + val;

Comment: how about `self.location='upload.php?category=' + val2+'&loc='+val;`?

Answer (score 1):

You look like you want the parameter from the url.

So change around your reload function:

```
function reload2(form)
        {   
            var val1=form.loc.options[form.loc.options.selectedIndex].value;
            var val2 = form.category.options[form.category.options.selectedIndex].value;
            self.location='upload.php?category=' + val2 + '&loc=' + val1;

        }
```

Then when the page is reloaded grab the new parameter:

```
//some on load functionality
var loc= getQueryParams(document.location.search).loc;
```

Using this function from [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

    var params = {}, tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}
```

Comment: actually sir, the problem is that I am having four dropdownlist 'STATES' 'DISTRICT' 'CATEGORY' 'SUBJECT'. The value of 'DISTRICT' and 'SUBJECT' changes with respect to the values in 'STATE' and 'CATEGORY' respectively. I am using two different onchange functions for both 'STATE' and 'CATEGORY'. like this codepen.io/anon/pen/gpgLxB When I select 'STATE' the page refreshes and the value is preserved but after that when I select 'CATEGORY' the value of 'STATE' is getting back to default value i.e choose. How to preserve both these values in a single function?

Answer (score 0):

you need to build up the query string like below.

```
function reload2(form)
            {   
                var val=form.loc.options[form.loc.options.selectedIndex].value;
                var val2 = form.category.options[form.category.options.selectedIndex].value;
                self.location='upload.php?category=' + val2 + '&loc=' + val;

            }
```

Comment: How does he access it when it reloads?

Comment: it didnt seem like he asked that.. he wanted to know how to get loc in the query string.. (which i answered). he has no code at all, no attempt to read it so i just supplied what he asked for.. if you want to know how to do it i can tell you but not answering something which he has not even given it ago at.

Comment: @JoshStevens actually sir, the problem is that I am having four dropdownlist 
 STATES DISTRICT
Category Subject. The value of district and subject changes with respect to the values in state and category respectively. I am using two different onchange functions for both state and category. like this

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpgLxB

When I select state the page refreshes and the value is preserved but after that when I select category the value of state is getting back to default value i.e choose. How to preserve both these values in a single function?